# Search and show record in google map with distance readius in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, distance

I want to search and show record in google map with distance readius in xcode 4, please provide me details about how I can implement google map as well as to allow user find locations with in a particular radius.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any google maps integration in Xcode...

Comment: Also, [what have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Yes, it is possible https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone. I am working on this

Comment: Xcode is the IDE, not the language or an API.

Comment: I am new to iphone develpment and I have just started working on this and this is my 1st app. if you can assist me then it would be good for me

Comment: You just posted a complete tutorial that seems to answer your question. What's the problem with it? You get the current location using [Core Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

Comment: I think this is possible to use google map in iphone app

Comment: With [`Map Kit`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html), yes. Note that iOS 6 doesn't use Google Maps anymore.

Comment: ok, thanks for updation. I am working on iOS 5.